# cat : Do not read stdin if no input file is given on the command line

Tags: command-line, bash, files, text, cat

I have a script that concatenates files with `cat`. It contains roughly the following line that hangs the script in reading the standard input if the directory contains no files:

```
cat /path/to/dir/* > concat.txt
```

Is there a way to either make `cat` not read anything from standard input and produce an empty output if no files exist at `/path/to/dir/`, or use another command to achieve the same?

Comment: In your case, if no files exist at `/path/to/dir/*`, `cat` will display an error message and not read anything from stdin. Have you actually tried it? `cat` reads from stdin only if there is **no parameter present**, not if there **is** a parameter that specifies a non-existent file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you have `nullglob` enabled so that `/path/to/dir/*` expands to nothing if no files are present in `/path/to/dir/`. You could, of course, disable `nullglob` (`shopt -u nullglob`) and get the default behaviour, where `/path/to/dir/*` remains as-is if nothing matches and `cat` will complain about the non-existent file:

```
$ cat /path/to/dir/*
cat: '/path/to/dir/*': No such file or directory
```

You could also just tack on a `/dev/null` at the end instead:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob; cat /path/to/dir/* /dev/null
$ echo $?
0
```

`cat` will get an immediate EOF from `/dev/null`, so it will write nothing and quit.

Comment: Thanks, `/dev/null` idea is especially attracting.